# Puzzling dependency of Boost.Python 1.54 (debug build) to Python27.lib on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, cmake, boost-python

I must be doing some kind of obvious mistake but after hours of fighting I'm unable to make further progress:

After upgrading to Boost 1.54, CMake 2.8.12 and Python 2.7.5 (all three from *slightly* earlier minor versions), the Python bindings of my [project](https://github.com/jupiter-jazz/appleseed) no longer link in Debug configuration (they link fine in Release). I'm building with VS 2012. **Everything was working properly before the update**.

I built Boost the standard way: `bootstrap.bat` followed by `b2 address-model=64 toolset=msvc-11.0`. My system has a Python 2.7 installation which is picked up by b2:

```
notice: [python-cfg] Configuring python...
notice: [python-cfg] Registry indicates Python 2.7 installed at "C:\Python27\"
notice: [python-cfg] Checking interpreter command "python"...
notice: [python-cfg] running command 'DIR /-C /A:S "C:\Python27\python.exe" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] running command 'python -c "from sys import *; print('version=%d.%d\nplatform=%s\nprefix=%s\nexec_prefix=%s\nexecutable=%s' % (version_info[0],version_info[1],platform,prefix,exec_prefix,executable))" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] ...requested configuration matched!
notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:
notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "python"
notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "C:\Python27\Include"
notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "C:\Python27\libs"
notice: [python-cfg]   DLL search path: "C:\Python27"
```

I don't have any other Python installation on my machine.

When I run CMake on my project, everything looks good too:

```
Found PythonLibs: optimized;C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib;debug;C:/Python27/libs/python27_d.lib (found version "2.7.5")
```

The relevant part of the linker's command line in Debug is as expected:

```
"C:\franz\dev\boost_1_54_0\stage\lib\libboost_python-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib" "C:\Python27\libs\python27_d.lib"
```

**When I finally build the project in Debug:**

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib'
```

Since nowhere is `python27.lib` mentioned on the linker's command line, I edited `libboost_python-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib` with an hexadecimal editor only to find out that it contains references to `python27.lib` (of the form `/DEFAULTLIB:"python27.lib"`) where I would have expected references to `python27_d.lib` instead (of which there is none).

**Am I doing something wrong when building Boost? Is this a known problem with Boost.Python in Boost 1.54?** Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update #1:** I tried again with Boost 1.51 and 1.50 and the same problem occurs, so it's not a regression in Boost.

**Update #2:** I removed the debug version of the Python lib (python27_d.lib) from my Python installation, thus reverting to a vanilla Python installation. I then rebuilt Boost 1.51 and my project (with CMake reporting a single library file as expected: `Found PythonLibs: C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib (found version "2.7.5")`). The problem persists, however the error message now mentions python27_d.lib: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27_d.lib'`!

**Update #3:** Using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) I could that python27_d.lib is not searched in `C:\Python27\libs\` where it actually resides:

```
3:35:28.0550683 PM  link.exe    10132   CreateFile  C:\franz\dev\appleseed\build\appleseed.python\python27_d.lib    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
3:35:28.0551846 PM  link.exe    10132   CreateFile  C:\franz\dev\boost_1_50_0\stage\lib\python27_d.lib  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
3:35:28.0552474 PM  link.exe    10132   CreateFile  C:\franz\dev\boost_1_50_0\stage\lib\Debug\python27_d.lib    PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
3:35:28.0553595 PM  link.exe    10132   CreateFile  C:\franz\dev\appleseed\build\appleseed.python\python27_d.lib    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
3:35:28.0556105 PM  link.exe    10132   CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\amd64\python27_d.lib NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
3:35:28.0559637 PM  link.exe    10132   CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64\python27_d.lib  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
3:35:28.0560984 PM  link.exe    10132   CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x64\python27_d.lib  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
3:35:28.0561741 PM  link.exe    10132   CreateFile  C:\franz\dev\appleseed\build\appleseed.python\python27_d.lib    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
```

**Update #4**: related question: [Visual C++ debug library naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923953/visual-c-debug-library-naming-convention)

Comment: Does `PYTHON_LIBRARIES` here https://github.com/jupiter-jazz/appleseed/blob/master/src/appleseed.python/CMakeLists.txt#L142 contain valid paths to the debug and release versions of the python libs?

Comment: Yeah this is all good. I've actually just fixed the problem, writing an answer now! Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed the problem, thanks to hints found in this post: [Visual C++ debug library naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923953/visual-c-debug-library-naming-convention).

Basically, the header file `pyconfig.h` that ships with Python (in `C:\Python27\include\`) forces linking to `python27_d.lib` in Debug build (via a `#pragma comment()` directive), regardless of whether this library exists or not.

The trick is to never include `Python.h` directly, but instead to include Boost's wrapper for that file, `boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp` which takes care of disabling the offending `#pragma comment()` directive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that boost has a special wrapper for that.

Answer (score 1):

Including `boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp`instead of `Python.h` allows you to use a release version of Python even when building a debug version of your program.

In case you have compiled yourself a debug version of Python, you can build a debug version of Boost that links against your debug version of Python.
(I am using VS2013, but the process should be the same with VS2010 and VS2012).

First create a text file called, eg, `my_config.bjam` conatining:

```
using python : 2.7                                     #version 
: C:\\Python-2.7.10-64bit-dbg-msvc12\\python_d.exe     #executable
: C:\\Python-2.7.10-64bit-dbg-msvc12\\include          #includes
: C:\\Python-2.7.10-64bit-dbg-msvc12\\libs             #libs
: <python-debugging>on ;
```

In order build a debug version of Boost, run `bootstrap.bat` first, then `b2` with the following options:

```
b2 ^
--build-dir=build__64bit-dbg-msvc12 ^
--build-type=complete ^
--stagedir=stage__64bit-dbg-msvc12 ^
--user-config=my_config.bjam ^
address-model=64 ^
python-debugging=on ^
define=BOOST_PYTHON_DEBUG ^
define=BOOST_PYTHON_NO_LIB ^
link=shared ^
toolset=msvc-12.0 ^
variant=debug ^
stage
```

This should do the trick. You should define `BOOST_PYTHON_DEBUG` also when compiling the debug version of your program.